# Restore automatic window title after rename-window in tmux

Tags: tmux

By default, tmux will show the title of the focused pane in the status bar. After using `rename-window` to set a title manually, how do you restore the default behavior?

First idea was to set a blank title, which didn't work. According to the soruce code, it sets the window option "automatic-rename" to 0, but doing things like `setw -g automatic-rename on` doesn't seem to have any effect (aside from confirming that the option was set).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
setw automatic-rename
```

This will work on Current window

```
setw -g automatic-rename
```

This will affect global session so all new window will be affected

Comment: This still does not restore any dynamically set window names while you had another name set, which is what I wanted (either restore old title, or revert to whatever was set last). But it doesn't look like this is possible without a patch so thanks anyways.

Comment: @tripflag, yes, it does. I've just tried it.

Comment: Just to make it clearer to everybody, you have to type your tmux prefix (commonly Ctrl-B) then colon `:` then your `setw` stuff

Comment: Or `tmux setw automatic-rename` at the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

@Ahed-eid's answer works only when you use `automatic-rename` which, as I think, isn't OC's case.

The correct answer is to:

- `set allow-rename on` - so your manual setting of window title can be overridden,
- `set automatic-rename on` - when you want tmux itself to set window name and title through its mechanism of terminal inspection
- `set automatic-rename off` - when you want to control window name and title from terminal (for example from a shell prompt)